# TypeError: React.createElement is not a function when creating custom render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I created a custom render method from react-testing-library in order to wrap my react components with the necessary providers however I get a type error when I run my test suite. Below I have my custom render, test, and test result respectively. I can't seem to figure out why it's throwing this error nor could I find a related answer from other posts. Any direction is greatly appreciated.

```
/* eslint-disable import/export */
import React, { FC, ReactElement } from 'react'
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react'
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl'
import messages from '~/src/locales/en-us.json'

const AllTheProviders: FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <IntlProvider locale="en-us" defaultLocale="en-us" messages={messages}>
      {children}
    </IntlProvider>
  )
}

const customRender = (
  ui: ReactElement,
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'>
) => render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options })

export * from '@testing-library/react'
export { customRender as render }
```

```
test('loads and displays greeting', () => {
  render(
    <Button
      textId="Click here!"
      type="primary"
      onClick={() => console.log('hi')}
    />
  )

  expect(screen.getByText('Click here!')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

```
 FAIL  src/components/library/Button/Button.test.tsx
  ● loads and displays greeting

    TypeError: React.createElement is not a function

      16 |   ui: ReactElement,
      17 |   options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'>
    > 18 | ) => render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options })
         |      ^
      19 |
      20 | export * from '@testing-library/react'
      21 | export { customRender as render }
```